# Remove forward slashes from url by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, slash

Trying to remove double slashes after domain. The following mod_rewrite expressions seem to work for URLs such as http://example.com//login, but do not work for domain//

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to convert URL from :

```
 http://example.com//login
```

To

```
 http://example.com/login
```

Would you please give me proper suggestion about how to remove double slashes from url?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should search root of problem in code asking yourself the question where this slash' doubling came from.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/+(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

You can also use RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch ^//+(.*)$ /$1
```